# Panel loses content when scrolled down

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, panel, paint

I have 2 panels inside one larger panel. The 2 inner panels auto size and the outer panel auto scrolls so that I can scroll down the content of my 2 panels together.

I use the paint event to draw grid lines on my right hand panel and there are label controls on both.

It all works fine (also resizing and being responsive) but when I'm scrolled down something weird happens.

**So say I call the things you see when your scrollbar is at the top the initial state. Then when  I scroll down and nothing of this initial state is visible and I resize/minimize/refresh... My right hand panel (with the grid lines and labels) greys out and everything dissapears.**

**Both the labels and graphics will only come back if I scroll up again and hit the bottom of the initial state.**

I know it might be hard to understand but feel free to ask for clarification on anything if you think you might be able to help.

[image: The initial state]
The initial state

[image: After scrolling down and resizing/minimize - restoring...]
After scrolling down and resizing/minimize - restoring...

[image: Everything appears again when I reach something which was in the initial state]

Everything appears again when I reach something which was in the initial state

The paint event for the right hand panel (although I doubt it'll be of much use)

```
private void panelPlanning_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= sub.Days + 1; i++)
        {
            if (toolStripButtonGrid.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                if (vertGrid)
                {
                    if (dashedVert)
                    {
                        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0), 1);
                        blackPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;

                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, i * labelDaysWidth, 0, i * labelDaysWidth, panelPlanning.Height);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0), 1);
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, i * labelDaysWidth, 0, i * labelDaysWidth, panelPlanning.Height);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < userList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (horGrid && toolStripButtonGrid.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                if (dashedHor)
                {
                    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0), 1);
                    blackPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;

                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 0, i * userHeight, panelPlanning.Width, i * userHeight);
                }
                else
                {
                    Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0), 1);
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 0, i * userHeight, panelPlanning.Width, i * userHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= sub.Days + 1; i++)
        {
            if (dtPickerStart.Value.AddDays(i) == DateTime.Today)
            {
                Pen blackpen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackpen, i * labelDaysWidth + labelDaysWidth / 2, 0, i * labelDaysWidth + labelDaysWidth / 2, panelPlanning.Height);
            }
        }

        if (userList.Count > 0)
        {
            panelPlanning.Height = userList.Count * userHeight;
            panelUsers.Height = userList.Count * userHeight;
        }
        if (nrResources == 0)
        {
            nrResources = 10;
        }
        userHeight = panel1.Height / nrResources;
    }
```

**EDIT**

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p4k9zilmy5pq6ev/RpBEe05B3j

A boiled down version of the solution giving the same problem.

**EDIT 2**

I have been able to fix most of the issues. Below is some code I changed (to see what I changed you can see the dropbox link above to compare.

```
private void this_beginResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ResizeBegin -= new EventHandler(this_beginResize);

    panelPlanning.Paint -= new PaintEventHandler(panelPlanning_Paint);

    this.SuspendLayout();
    SuspendDrawing(panelTimeline);
    SuspendDrawing(panelPipeLine);
    SuspendDrawing(panel1);
}
```

I used to remove the ResizeEnd event and add it again later. I changed that into the ResizeBegin, since this makes more sense to me.

```
private void this_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panelTimeline.Controls.Clear();
    sub = dtPickerEnd.Value - dtPickerStart.Value;
    addDayLabels(sub);

    panelUsers.Controls.Clear();
    addUserLabels();

    panelPlanning.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panelPlanning_Paint);

    ResumeDrawing(panel1);
    ResumeDrawing(panelTimeline);
    ResumeDrawing(panelPipeLine);
    this.ResumeLayout();

    if (userList.Count > 0)
    {
        panelPlanning.Height = userList.Count * userHeight;
        panelUsers.Height = userList.Count * userHeight;
    }
    if (nrResources == 0)
    {
        nrResources = 10;
    }
    userHeight = panel1.Height / nrResources;
    lastPanelHeight = panel1.Height;

    panelPlanning.Controls.Clear();
    addPlanning();

    this.ResizeBegin += new EventHandler(this_beginResize);
}
```

When the resize is at an end I used to make the planning panel the height of the container panel. This was probably the main reason my content was lost when I scrolled down.
I replaced this with the code from my paint event to calculate the heights. I also assigned a variable lastPanelHeight which keeps track of the panel height for the method below.
Maximize and restore events are called here before they are actually executed, so I need to know what they have to be restored to.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x0112) // WM_SYSCOMMAND
    {
        // Check your window state here
        if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0xF030) || m.WParam == new IntPtr(0xF120)) // Maximize event - SC_MAXIMIZE from Winuser.h
        {
            //Same code as the two above combined but with lastPanelHeight as value to do the calculations with
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

**HOWEVER**, I'm still experiencing issues. When I resize and the form gets bigger or I restore the window from maximized or minimized state, the scrollbar acts in a weird way. 
When it's all the way down and the form gets bigger it stays at the same height in the panel, thus moving up.
On a restore the scrollbar always goes all the way back to the top.
*Any ideas?*

Comment: An screenshot and some of your code are welcome.

Comment: I'll try and post some screenshots. Which code would you like to see? the Paint event for the grid lines?

Comment: Any code that you think is relevant. Does what you described happen when you scroll a little down?

Comment: It happens whenever nothing from the initial state is visible and a resize (thus a refresh of the panel) happens. And by initial state I mean everything you can see when your scrollbar is at the top. I don't think the code is relevant but I'll post the paint event in a bit :p

Comment: Both the screenshots and code for the paint event of the right hand panel are added

Comment: the problem is in the paint event, you will need to save it to bitmap first en constantly show that bitmap on the panel.

Comment: Could you please explain why? And could you show how too? :)

Comment: How can we reproduce your problem? I've created a test project like what you described, but it works without any problem. If possible, create a sample project with the same problem, and upload it somewhere so we can have a look at it.

Comment: I've edited my post with a link to dropbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an initial improvement (see question EDIT2) I focussed on the scrollbar and got that to work after a while too. The trick is too keep track of the scrollbar value and the panel height before the resize and compute it with the new height after the resize. The scroll position is set like this but the scrollbar would still show in another position. This can be fixed by enabling and disabling the scrollbar. full code (mind that there is code for a maximize and restore too) below.

```
/// The beginning of a form resize
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void this_beginResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lastLocation = this.Location;
    this.ResizeBegin -= new EventHandler(this_beginResize);

    panelPlanning.Paint -= new PaintEventHandler(panelPlanning_Paint);
    scrollvalue = panel1.VerticalScroll.Value;
    lastHeight = panel1.Height;

    this.SuspendLayout();
    SuspendDrawing(panelTimeline);
    SuspendDrawing(panelPipeLine);
    SuspendDrawing(panel1);
}

/// <summary>
/// Called when the form is done resizing
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void this_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Location != lastLocation)
    {
        lastLocation = this.Location;
        return;
    }

    panelTimeline.Controls.Clear();
    sub = dtPickerEnd.Value - dtPickerStart.Value;
    addDayLabels(sub);

    panelUsers.Controls.Clear();
    addUserLabels();

    panelPlanning.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panelPlanning_Paint);

    ResumeDrawing(panel1);
    ResumeDrawing(panelTimeline);
    ResumeDrawing(panelPipeLine);
    this.ResumeLayout();

    if (userList.Count > 0)
    {
        panelPlanning.Height = userList.Count * userHeight;
        panelUsers.Height = userList.Count * userHeight;
    }
    if (nrResources == 0)
    {
        nrResources = 10;
    }
    userHeight = panel1.Height / nrResources;

    panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = scrollvalue * panel1.Height / lastHeight;
    panel1.VerticalScroll.Enabled = false;

    panelPlanning.Controls.Clear();
    addPlanning();

    this.ResizeBegin += new EventHandler(this_beginResize);

    panel1.VerticalScroll.Enabled = true;
    panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = scrollvalue * panel1.Height / lastHeight;
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles maximize and restore
/// </summary>
/// <param name="m"></param>
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x0112) // WM_SYSCOMMAND
    {
        // Check your window state here
        if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0xF030) || m.WParam == new IntPtr(0xF120)) // Maximize event - SC_MAXIMIZE from Winuser.h
        {
            this.ResizeBegin -= new EventHandler(this_beginResize);

            panelPlanning.Paint -= new PaintEventHandler(panelPlanning_Paint);
            scrollvalue = panel1.VerticalScroll.Value;

            if (panel1.Height != 0)
            {
                lastHeight = panel1.Height;
            }

            this.SuspendLayout();
            SuspendDrawing(panelTimeline);
            SuspendDrawing(panelPipeLine);
            SuspendDrawing(panel1);

            panel1.VerticalScroll.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);

    if (m.Msg == 0x0112) // WM_SYSCOMMAND
    {
        // Check your window state here
        if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0xF030) || m.WParam == new IntPtr(0xF120)) // Maximize event - SC_MAXIMIZE from Winuser.h
        {
            panelTimeline.Controls.Clear();
            sub = dtPickerEnd.Value - dtPickerStart.Value;
            addDayLabels(sub);

            panelUsers.Controls.Clear();
            addUserLabels();

            panelPlanning.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panelPlanning_Paint);

            ResumeDrawing(panel1);
            ResumeDrawing(panelTimeline);
            ResumeDrawing(panelPipeLine);
            this.ResumeLayout();

            if (userList.Count > 0)
            {
                panelPlanning.Height = userList.Count * userHeight;
                panelUsers.Height = userList.Count * userHeight;
            }
            if (nrResources == 0)
            {
                nrResources = 10;
            }
            userHeight = panel1.Height / nrResources;

            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = scrollvalue * panel1.Height / lastHeight;
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Enabled = false;

            panelPlanning.Controls.Clear();
            addPlanning();

            this.ResizeBegin += new EventHandler(this_beginResize);

            panel1.VerticalScroll.Enabled = true;
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = scrollvalue * panel1.Height / lastHeight;
        }
    }
}
```